# ajax call returning Network error>> 404

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
if(activePage.attr('id') === 'register_page') {
    $(document).on('click', '#submit', function() { // catch the form's submit event
        if($('#fname').val().length > 3 && $('#lname').val().length > 3 && $('#username').val().length > 4 && $('#email').val().length > 5 ){

            userHandler.username = $('#username').val();

            // Send data to server through the Ajax call
            //$.post( "http://127.0.0.1/projects/register2.php", $( "#register-user" ).serialize() );

            // action is functionality we want to call and outputJSON is our data
            $.ajax({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1/projects/services/register.php',
            data: {action : 'registration', formData : $('#register-user').serialize()},
            type: 'post',                  
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'JSON ',
            beforeSend: function() {
                    // This callback function will trigger before data is sent
                    $.mobile.loading('show'); // show Ajax spinner
                },
                complete: function() {
                    // trigger on data sent/received complete   
                    $.mobile.loading('hide'); // hide Ajax spinner
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    // Check if registration successful
                    if(result.status == 'success') {
                        userHandler.status = result.status;
                        $.mobile.changePage("#categories");                        
                    } else if(result.status == 'failure'){
                         $("#register-error").text("System failure... please try again!").show().fadeOut(3000);
                    }
                    else if(result.status == 'taken'){
                        alert('Username or email is taken!');
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error ) {
                    // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action               
                    //alert('Network error has occurred please try again!'); >> kanyagia hapa
                    $("#register-error").text(xhr.status+ "Network error... please check and try agin!").show().fadeOut(3000);
                }
            });
```

Comment: You are a little short on detail here. Where is the problem happening, What is the complete error message etc. We are not clarevoyant and we cannot see over your shoulder

Comment: `The 404 or Not Found error message is an HTTP standard response code indicating that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested.` Check the `url` parameter

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry for the shallow question, I was in a timed competition and didn't have enough time to type the full question.. my problem was trying to access files on localhost from intel xdk (jquery mobile) application. My emulator could not find the url to the file despite testing it in my browser and confirming that it worked just fine. I have been stuck there the whole day, apparently I lost the competition but I still need to know. my PHP file is just okay, but the intel xdk app cannot get it on the local server. I haven't found what am missing.

Comment: Is it not considered cheating, getting outside help while in a competition?

Comment: @RiggsFolly aha, it might be.. but it is not bad to seek a little help from my favourite site>> Stackoverflow...   I didnt see any error, maybe something invincible is preventing the intel xdk emulator from accessing the localhost....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php file>> as shown below with Access headers works fine, without the access, the xdk emulator returns network error

```
                <?php
      header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');
require './services/config.php';

if(!empty($_POST))
{
    $errors=0;
    if(empty($_POST['fname']) || empty($_POST['lname']) || empty($_POST['username'])
            || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['pword']))
    {
        $errors++;
        $error_msg="Please fill all the fields";
        $status =(true);
       echo '{"empty":'.json_encode($status).'}';
    }
    //pick all the data
    $fname=$_POST['fname'];
    $lname=$_POST['lname'];
    $usern=$_POST['username'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $pass=$_POST['pword'];
    $role=$_POST['role'];

    //encrypt pw
    $encrypt_pw=  md5($pass);
    //check if errors are still 0 and check user existence
    if($errors==0)
    {
        $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:aa OR email=:bb";
        $query_params=array(
            ':aa'=>$usern,
            ':bb'=>$email
        );

        try{
            $stmt=$db->prepare($query);
            $result=$stmt->execute($query_params);
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            $errors++;
            $error_msg="Server failure... please try again";
             $status =("0");
              echo '{"status":'.json_encode($status).'}';
        }
        $row=$stmt->fetch();
        if($row)
        {
           $errors++;
           $error_msg="Username or email already exists"; 
           $status =(true);
            echo '{"exists":'.json_encode($status).'}';
        }
        //if errors still 0
        if($errors==0)
        {
            $query="INSERT INTO users(fname, lname, username, email, password, role, created_at) VALUES(:aa, :bb, :cc, :dd, :ee,:ff, NOW())";
            $query_params=array(
                ':aa'=>$fname,
                ':bb'=>$lname,
                ':cc'=>$usern,
                ':dd'=>$email,
                ':ee'=>$encrypt_pw,
                ':ff'=>$role
            );

            try{
                $stmt=$db->prepare($query);
                $result=$stmt->execute($query_params);
            } catch (Exception $ex) {
                $errors++;
                $error_msg="Server failure... please try again";
                $status = array("status" => "failure");
                 echo json_encode($status);
            }

            if($errors==0)
            {
                //registration successful
                $success_msg="You registered";
                $status =(true);
                 echo '{"success":'.json_encode($status).'}';
            }
        }

    }

}
/*
some interface here..
*/
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

404 means the URL you tried to reach wasn't found. I suspect, from a comment above your ajax url, that it should be `http://127.0.0.1/projects/register2.php` instead of `http://127.0.0.1/projects/register.php`.

Comment: the uncommented URL is the correct one, I changed it.. Actually running it from my chrome browser it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

A 404 error means the resource the call is trying to obtain does not exist, so you might want to check where that call is going and what it is trying to get back.

The call here is also going to a specific IP address, so I'm assuming you are testing this locally, but what you set there may not be running if it is returning a 404.

Comment: I have explained in my answer to @RiggsFolly the whole issue, basically it is the Intel XDK emulator that seems not to get my php file from localhost. I am willing to share the php file in case it might help..

Comment: I see. Well there is no way to directly run PHP code in XDK If that is what you're trying to do. That may be what is going on.

Comment: @ anthonyjruffa nope, the php code is on local server (Xampp htdocs) and am accessing it from intel  xdk emulator...

Comment: Really. That's interesting. In that case you can share the PHP file.

Comment: actually the php file was just okay, xampp server was the one preventing access from the intel xdk emulator, so i found a workaround, I had to add php access headers on top of the php files.

Comment: I have answered with my file at the top,,,

Comment: my problem now remains with getting the result back to jquery mobile and displaying on html elements, it is not working, i have set the ids in html and then set the ids with the text in jquery mobile depending on reply from the php server, that part is not working, nothing is being displayed on html interface...